# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when communicating with my ESP8266 over WiFi

Tags: networking, webserver, wifi, esp8266, esp8266wifi

Derived from the following [code](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/server-examples.html#put-it-together).

I uploaded that code to my ESP8266 and it's all good and okay when I communicate with it with my laptop while my laptop is connected to my network with a LAN cable.

The problem is: when I try to communicate with the ESP with my laptop or phone over Wi-Fi I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` though they rarely work and communicate. I tried another phone another router, and did a factory reset to my router, and all the same.

I know that there is an option in the router that is called AP Isolation and it's been checked and it's disabled.

My question is: What could possibly be the reason for this error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when I communicate with ESP8266 with that code?

If someone could help me I would be pleased as I am stuck in this situation.

The ESP code (same as the link):

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "*****";
const char* password = "*******";

WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.printf("Connecting to %s ", ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println(" connected");

  server.begin();
  Serial.printf("Web server started, open %s in a web browser\n", WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str());
}

// prepare a web page to be send to a client (web browser)
// the connection will be closed after completion of the response
// the page will be refreshed automatically every 5 sec
String prepareHtmlPage() {
  String htmlPage = String("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n") +
                    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
                    "Connection: close\r\n" +
                    "Refresh: 5\r\n" + "\r\n" +
                    "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" + "<html>" +
                    "Analog input:  " + String(analogRead(A0)) +
                    "</html>" + "\r\n";
  return htmlPage;
}


void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();

  // wait for a client (web browser) to connect 
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("\n[Client connected]");
    while (client.connected()) {
      // read line by line what the client (web browser) is requesting
      if (client.available()) {
        String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
        Serial.print(line);
        // wait for end of client's request, that is marked with an empty line
        if (line.length() == 1 && line[0] == '\n') {
          client.println(prepareHtmlPage());
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    delay(1); // give the web browser time to receive the data

    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("[Client disconnected]");
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the IP address of the Arduino once it has connected to WiFi? Is it the same address you are trying to reach from your laptop? Are the laptop and the Arduino in the same network according to the netmask? Add some Serial.println()s in your code to see what happens where.

Comment: The problem is it's now working perfectly I am sure that I was using the right IP address and subnet mask, I am afraid that this problem might come again as I did nothing, I will do several tries like resetting the router, changing it, change the IP and any other change I can make and then I will get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

I hope its not too late and it helps someone in need.
You need to do 2 things

Before `WiFi.begin()`, you need to add

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
```

Second, you need to

```
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
```

in setup()

```
if (MDNS.begin("esp8266")) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
}
```

and in loop()

```
MDNS.update();
```

Lastly, do not forget to add the following in every server response. Else, you will hit CORS error.

```
server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Please dont forget to add supporting libraries. Let me know if it works. Demo code would look like the below

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

const char* ssid = "<your SSID>";
const char* password = "<your WIFI Password>>";
int serverPort = 80;
int boardBaud = 115200;

ESP8266WebServer server(serverPort);

void handleRoot() {
  server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  server.send(200, "text/html", "<h1>Hello World</h1>");
}

void handleNotFound() {
  if (server.method() == HTTP_OPTIONS)
    {
        server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "10000");
        server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT,POST,GET,OPTIONS");
        server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        server.send(204);
    }
    else
    {
        server.send(404, "text/plain", "Error");
    }
}

void setup(void) {
  
  Serial.begin(boardBaud);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  if (MDNS.begin("esp8266")) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
  }

  server.on("/", handleRoot);

  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

  server.begin();
  
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop(void) {
  server.handleClient();
  MDNS.update();
}
```

Comment: it's not too late at all, thanks for your response,
I noticed that I added that `WIFI_STA` mode a while ago, I haven't encountered any problem so far.
My question is, mDNS library is used here only to make a domain name for my ESP?
also, the header set is only for that domain name?
so if I don't need to assign a domain name I don't have to use these two things right?

Comment: You are correct